# Custom UIActionSheet squished on iPad

Tags: ios, ipad

I have read through several similar questions here on stack but so far none of the answers seem to fit.  Therefore it must be something so blatantly obvious that I will have to flog myself later once it gets answered.

The code works fine on iPhone but not iPad, the action sheet has little to no height. There is no tool bar and it is fired off a normal UIButton.  I have considered a popover however this is a universal app so I would rather not re-wright the same code twice for both iPhone and iPad and try and keep the app as light as possible.

I have tried showFromRect and showFromTabbar.

Thanks

Code:

```
    -(IBAction) setDateTime:(id) sender {

        dateSheet = [[UIActionSheet alloc] initWithTitle:nil delegate:nil cancelButtonTitle:nil destructiveButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];   
        [dateSheet setActionSheetStyle:UIActionSheetStyleBlackTranslucent];

        CGRect pickerFrame = CGRectMake(0, 44, 0, 0);

        UIDatePicker *appointmentDayPicker = [[UIDatePicker alloc] initWithFrame:pickerFrame];

        [appointmentDayPicker setDatePickerMode:UIDatePickerModeDateAndTime];

        [dateSheet addSubview:appointmentDayPicker];
        [appointmentDayPicker release];

         UIToolbar *controlToolBar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, dateSheet.bounds.size.width, 44)];

        [controlToolBar setBarStyle:UIBarStyleBlack];
        [controlToolBar sizeToFit];

        UIBarButtonItem *spacer = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:nil action:nil];

        UIBarButtonItem *setButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Set" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(dismissDateSet)];

        UIBarButtonItem *cancelButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Cancel" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:self action:@selector(cancelDateSet)];

       [controlToolBar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:spacer, cancelButton,setButton, nil] animated:NO];
       [spacer release];
       [setButton release];
       [cancelButton release];

       [dateSheet addSubview:controlToolBar];
       [controlToolBar release];

       if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad) {
           [dateSheet showFromRect:CGRectMake(100,100, 320, 485) inView:self.view animated:YES];
           [dateSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 200, 485)];
       } else {
           [dateSheet showInView:self.view];
           [dateSheet setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 485)];
       }
    }
```

EDIT:  Adding pic

[image]

Comment: You set the dataSheet bounds with to 200, shouldn't be 320, which I think is the defauult width of the picker view ?

Comment: Yes that was from messing around but issue is the height. Its only showing about 10 high. I can just see the picker so I know its in there.